# How can I force Netbeans to always open XML files in the text view?

Tags: performance, netbeans-6.9

My work pc is the slowest machine on the planet.  It consistently takes **SIX MINUTES** to open a 13 line XML file (the `persistence.xml`).  I think it's because it's opening it in the XML editor mode and all I want to see is the text.

Is there a way to enforce this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question can be closed or deleted but I thought I would mention my solution.  Turns out, the corporate virus scanning is so strict around here that once I disabled real-time scanning, it went from 6 minutes to 5 seconds.  Yeah FSecure.